# SQL exception catcher in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to catch a SQL exception when executing a query in Entity Framework 6. In EF Core, there is a `DbCommandInterceptor` and its method `CommandFailed(DbCommand, CommandErrorEventData)` for this.

Does EF 6 have any analogues, or how can I implement it in EF 6?

Comment: Why do you want that in the first place, either in EF Core or EF Classic? The specifics matter. Optimistic concurrency exceptions need to be handled use case by use case, not hidden. Centralized logging ... there isn't one in .NET Framework/EF 6, so if you want a generic exception logger you'll have to adopt it to whatever library you use for logging.

Comment: The [EF 6 Logging and Interception docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) show the logging and interception features available in EF 6. The [logging example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception#example-logging-to-nlog) uses an IDbCommandInterceptor and NLog to check for errors and log them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to make retry on deadlock victim exception.

Comment: Fix the bug that causes the exception instead of trying to cover it up. EF use optimistic concurrency which means deadlocks should rarely if ever happen. No locks or even a connection is kept after reading data. Saving changes doesn't read data. A DbContext is a Unit of Work that persists *all* pending changes in a single database transaction, using a new dedicated connection, which means the chance of deadlocks is *very* small. If you use explicit database transactions you break the UoW pattern.

Comment: If retry on deadlock is indeed needed, check the latest answers in [Implementing retry logic for deadlock exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159326/implementing-retry-logic-for-deadlock-exceptions). EF 6 allows you to specify a retry execution strategy. If EF is used correctly, deadlocks may arise before some other code is updating the same rows EF is trying to update in the wrong order. In such a case you may encounter concurrency errors after retrying.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you. The execution strategy is exactly what I was looking for.